# How to redirect to another link with javascript in a wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress geo theme driven website where user can search for events. When I start to write anything in the text box for searching event, then a auto completer suggestion  comes in (which is a plugin). After clicking any suggestion  it fills the textbox, and submits a form to index page.

But I need, after clicking the suggestion  it will fill the text box(which is currently OK) and redirect the page to another link to same site like this: `http://sitename.com/events/text-comes-from-text-box`.
***"text-comes-from-text-box"*** is the text which will come form the text box after clicking the suggestion.

Suggestions come from a plugin and suggestions come to this page "review_searchform.php". Suggestions come as `<div id='ac_results'><ul><li>`.
I am trying to find out,if I click on the `<li>` which is coming from the plugins is responding. For do that I used this code in 
`review_searchform.php` this page, but it's not working. My code is below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery("#ac_results ul li").click(function() {
    alert("test 2");

});
```

If it would work, then I would add redirect code here. 
I think to solve this problem, it does not need PHP or WordPress functions. It only needs Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Can you add html code of that suggestion?

Comment: <div style="display: none; position: absolute; width: 135px; top: 297px; left: 224px;" class="ac_results">

<ul><li class=""><span> matches</span>suggestion1</li>
<li><span> matches</span>suggestion2</li>
</ul>
</div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok lets say your suggestion box is a div with `class="suggestion"`.

We want to redirect our page to this suggestions text as address.

Example of your suggestion html

```
<div class="suggestion">Air Control Service</div>
```

After clicking this link your visitor must go to this address right? :

```
http://sitename.com/events/Air-Control-Service
```

Ok then lets write our jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //Take care to conflict issue
  $(".suggestion").on("click", function(){ //When visitor clicks your suggestion
    var eventText = $(this).text(); //Get text from suggestion 
    eventText = eventText.replace(" ","-"); //Replace "-" for " "
    var base = "http://sitename.com/events/"; //Set your base address
    window.location.href = base + eventText; //Redirect your visitor
  });
});
```

That is all, I hope this will be helpfull.

Edit: Changed my script to `.on()` version. Now ajax returns also included in events.

Comment: Unfortunately its not working.Suggestions are coming from a wordpress plugin.div(#ac_results) , ul ,li are not the part of our page where user writes event name, it comes from a plugin via ajax. I think this is making the problems.

Comment: Then you must se .on() event of jquery

Answer (score 3):

`window.location = your_url` will make your browser redirect immediately

Comment: I need to pass the value of the textbox after clicking the suggestion. But when I click on the suggestion it fills the text box but it does not redirect with the value of text box.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#ac_results ul li").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        window.location = $(this).text();
    });
});
```